# MYSQL Query: output the count of insertions in the Log table

Tags: sql, mysql, database

I've got 2 tables:

----Users-----

- id (int)
- username (varchar)

----Log-----

- id (int)
- user_id (int)
- logged (datetime)

Every time the user logs in, a record is inserted into the Log table. I would like to create a statement that will output:

EXAMPLE:

Jason -> 96
Mary -> 54
Jack -> 53

I've been pulling my hair out with this SQL statement required to do this. Any insight?

Comment: More info please. What is "96"?  How many times should each user appear in the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select Users.username , Count (Log.user_id)
From Users, Log
WHERE Users.id=Log.user_id
Group by log.user_id
```

Comment: You are welcome . you can vote the question up and mark it as answer if it helps :)

Comment: dangerous group by, in standard SQL you should have the Users.username in the GROUP BY, this *extended group by syntax* on MySQl is dangerous, should be avoided for beginners. I would even add the User.id in the Group by and select to avoid duplicate names if username is not unique.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to make an assumption from the small amount of info given. I think your best bet would be something like:

select u.username, ' -> ', l.user_id from Users u, Log l where l.user_id = u.id